# upload user profile picture in php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I created a simple upload form, all the code is working perfectly but when I upload 2kb,20kb,26kb, then the pic will uploaded but when I try to upload 60kb,66kb then the page will stuck on loading,
I don't know why this happen and I also changed the max-upload-size in php.ini.
can anybody tell me why this is happening?

**Signup.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

this is all I have please check it...

**Note** Just tell me a solution,When I test  the above code on window xp, it will run correctly and i upload up to 103kb file, but it will not work on window 8, and create problem like I mention above... is the Xammp latest version have bugs, or what is the problem?

**Note** The error is not the code, the error is logical, so please be specific and to the point.
Please add the explanatory answer....

Comment: what would happen if a user uploaded a `.php` file using your uploader?

Comment: I tried try catch block but no error show, and the main problem is that I discussed above in my question. 
and  serakfalcon I know you mean the extension validation, I will put it latter on but for now I am stuck in uploading..

Comment: what is the resolution of the uploaded picture ? have you tried with a different browser ?

Comment: what do you mean with $image['name'] = $image['name'] ???

Comment: the resolution doesn't mean, and the $image['name']=$image['name']

Comment: the $image['name']=$image['name'] is an extra step just ignore it, focus on the main problem..

Answer (score 1):

As @Shikata wrote, be careful with:

```
$TARGET_PATH = "images/";
$image['name'] =$image['name'];
$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];
```

Instead just use:

```
$TARGET_PATH = "images/".$image['name'];
```

And like the other answers, you must check the validation! Also erase the strar_session(); from connection.php

Also as sugestion try to check PDO prepared-statements http://php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (I really suggest reading this, please give it a try, it can give you a more secure way to implement queries by binding parameters and by that way avoiding some SQL injections problems)

(Sorry for not going to the point with the previous answer)
That's about the code, as much as I try it (few time), about the upload problem maybe checking the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. If the problem is still there try checking `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time`. I hope you get a solution.

Comment: Dear Charles Rojas my problem is not the name it is the uploading problem that I am facing.... and I already use PDO->prepare statements in my code..
Please be specific, by the way thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

may be its file permission error

in linux open terminal and **enable** file permission

> chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/folder_name (or your path)

to **disable** :-

> chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/folder_name

or go to your file>right click >change permission from read only to read and write

Answer (score 0):

try to search my.ini in your wamp or xamp folder and edit max_allowed_packets to a little bit larger sized.. thanks

Comment: Did you mean ```php.ini```?

Comment: my.ini is different file from php.ini.. its just located at wamp/bin/mysql well it is mysql setting.. if you can see my.ini file then try to edit max_allowed_packets